# Java XPath : iterating over a collection of nodes and their indices

Tags: java, xpath

I have this XML instance document:

```
<entities>
    <person>James</person>
    <person>Jack</person>
    <person>Jim</person>
</entities>
```

And with the following code I iterate over the person nodes and print their names:

```
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("/entities/person");
NodeList nodes = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
for (int i = 0 ; i < nodes.getLength() ; i++) {
    Node node = nodes.item(i);
    String nodeName = node.getNodeName();
    String name  = xpath.compile("text()").evaluate(node).trim();
    System.out.printf("node type = %s, node name = %s\n", nodeName, name);
}
```

Now what I would like is to also have access to the index of each node.

I know I can trivially get it from the `i` loop variable but I want to get it as an **XPath** expression instead, preferably in no different way than I get the value of the `text()` **XPath** expression.

My use-case is that I am trying to handle all attributes I collect as **XPath** expressions (which I load at run-time from a config file) so that I minimize non-generic code, so I don't want to treat the index as a special case.

Comment: The appropriate XPath expression to get the element's text content with `evaluate` would be `"."`, not `"text()"`.  In this example they'd return the same thing because each person has just one text node child, but in general they're different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to use a trick like counting the preceding siblings

```
count(preceding-sibling::person)
```

which gives 0 for the first `person`, 1 for the second one, etc.

Comment: So, these `Node` objects I get when iterating on the outer XPath expression (`/entities/person`) are not "detached" so to speak from the outer document, you can still navigate the graph if given a single one of these `Node` instances. I am sure I 've gotten the terminology all wrong but you get what I'm saying.

Comment: @MarcusJuniusBrutus correct, every DOM `Node` maintains a link to the document that owns it, and its position in the tree (parent, previous and next siblings, and children).

Answer (score 0):

Try using *position()*

```
String index  = xpath.compile("position()").evaluate(node).trim();
```

Comment: position() evals to 1 for all persons (which if I understand correctly makes sense as it is evaluated in the context of `node` and not the whole document).